# Can a Pokemon be caught on the Pokewalker without reducing it to 1HP?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver, pokemon-hgss-pokewalker

With the Pokemon HeartGold/SoulSilver Pokewalker, do you always have to reduce a Pokemon to 1HP to catch it, or can you catch a Pokemon that has, say, 2HP left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can catch a Pokemon with more than 1HP left, but it's not always guaranteed.

For reference, I've caught a Pokemon with 3HP left, and I've never failed to catch one that had 1HP left.